# When discussing a “feathering, counterweighted propeller” where are the counterweights?

Tags: propeller

We are learning about propellers in school. To my understanding, generally a non-feathering, non counterweighted prop uses centrifugal twisting moments to lower blade pitch while oil pressure is used to increase.

This is flipped with counterweighted props right? We use the centrifugal force of the counterweights to increase angle, while oil decreases it?. But, where in the world are these counterweights? None of my books or any google searches tells me much.

Answer (score 3):

They're at the blade roots. If the propeller has a spinner, they are usually hidden, but if there is no spinner, they stick out like sore thumbs. Oil drives the blades fine, the weights drive them coarse, and if the prop is feathering, and the feathered position being beyond coarse, there will also be an internal spring to drive the blades all the way to feather in case the rotational speed isn't enough for the counter weights to do the job.

On a feathering counterweight prop there are also centrifugal pitch stops inside the hub that limit the prop to normal coarse pitch until the RPM is above 500-800 rpm, when they move out of the way to allow the blades to feather if the engine fails while making power. The stops keep the blades at coarse pitch when you shut down normally. When the engine is making power, all you have to do is dump the oil pressure and the prop will feather by the weights, helped by the feathering spring.

[image]